# "He had been raised a brave man... whom only a native woman made a good wife."

Tags: phrase-usage, verbs, pronouns

*"Her only son **had been raised a brave and respected gentleman** in their community, **whom** only a native woman **could make a good wife**."*

Please, could anyone tell me if this sentence is properly formulated?

My concerns are directed towards the "**had been *raised a brave* and respected gentleman**" more exactly the "**raised a**" part. Shall it be rather... "**raised as a**" or "**raised into a**".

As well, the formulation *"only a native woman could make **him** a good wife"* can it be rephrased in the above mentioned form, using **whom** (obviously for stylistic reasons and also for joining two sentences)?

Comment: Did you find it somewhere, or is it a sentence that you have written yourself? If the latter, could you provide a rephrasing to explain what you want the sentence to mean?

Comment: No. I wrote it myself. I am talking about a young man's mother being unfriendly towards her daughter in law, whom he chose regardless of their community's tradition of marrying locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is leaving out a couple of prepositions that are understood. The first one you have found on your own: *raised as a* (we wouldn't use *into*; we would say *grown into a*, though). The other one is *for*, as in *for whom only*.

So:

> Her only son had been raised as a brave and respected gentleman in their community, for whom only a native woman could make a good wife.

If you want to use *him* you should break it into two complete sentences, so:

> Her only son had been raised as a brave and respected gentleman in their community, and only a native woman could make him a good wife.

This works, but it is a bit ambiguous: it could mean that only a native woman could make him into a good wife! So, this is a bit clearer:

> Her only son had been raised as a brave and respected gentleman in their community, and only a native woman could make a good wife for him.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had mistakenly assumed that where you inserted the preposition "for" I should've added "to". But that wouldn't have reflected his perception, rather hers, as in "I am a bad person to X", versus "I am a bad person for X", meaning in X's mind, not that I acted bad against him.  Your explanation is perfectly logical and easy to understand. I appreciate!

Comment: You're very welcome.